# opengl : can two different vectors bind to the same vertex array object?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have two vectors, 
    std::vector col and 
    std::vector pos,

my shader is as follows:

```
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec3 PColor;\n"
"out vec3 color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"color = PColor;\n"
"}\0";


 const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"in vec4 PColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"color = PColor;\n"
"}\n\0";
```

can I do the following to bind both the pos and col to the same VAO

```
void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
glGenBuffers(1, &posbuffer);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int) * pos.size(), &pos.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GL_INT), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
//glBindVertexArray(0); delete
glGenBuffers(1, &colbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * col.size(),  &col.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindVertexArray(0);  
}
```

I want to make my program draw a circle, but core dumped, so I think there maybe some problem with my VAO bind. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you unbinding your VAO (and failing to re-bind it) after the first `glVertexAttribPointer()` call?  Why are you binding a random VAO called `1` after the second `glVertexAttribPointer()` call?

Comment: `glBindVertexArray(1)` doesn't make sense, you should generate the vertex array with `glGenVertexArrays` and then bind the result.  You should never be binding hard-coded constants, except 0.

Comment: oops, I made  a mistake. I change those two lines, but stilll not working.I edited above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should generate a VAO before generate VBOs

   ```
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao[object_id]);
   glBindVertexArray(vao[object_id]);

   glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[0]);
   glBindBuffer(target, vbo[0]);
   glBufferData(target, size, data1, dataType);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[UV]);
   glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[UV], 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);

   glGenBuffers(1, &vbo[1]);
   glBindBuffer(target, vbo[1]);
   glBufferData(target, size, data2, dataType);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[POSITION]);
   glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[POSITION], 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);
   ```
2. the position vector must be float not int since it will be vec2 in the shader
3. I am not sure but It seems there is no stride in your array if so don't put 2 * sizeof(GL_INT) and 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)

**Update**
When you draw the object, you must bind the vao you generated

```
  glBindVertexArray(vao[object_id]);
```

If you don't update any value of your array, you don't need to bind any vbos in the render loop. However if you need to update the vertices for color or position, you must call those functions.

```
  glBindVertexArray(vao[object_id]);
  glBindBuffer(target, vbo[object_id]);   
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(the_array), &the_array[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. so when I want to render the circle, I need to first bind vao[0] and vao[1] and then gldraw , is it correct ?

Comment: @tiger you need to bind only one vao which has two vbos

Comment: @tiger don't forget glviewport() gluseprogram() gldrawxxxx() things

Comment: I have that, after change the  CreateVertexBuffer(), I still got core dump... so I'm checking it. But your explain is very clear. Thanks.